# Cómo puedo enviar informacion de un select tag "<select>" a mi controlador?

Tags: html, mvc, select

Tengo lo siguiente:

```
            <select id="client_type" class="form-select-sm" name="select">
                <option value="Automático" selected>Automático</option>
                <option value="Manual">Manual</option>
            </select>
```

y quisiera que se envie por un formulario el valor que obtengo al seleccionar cualquier opcion de mi select. Estoy usando un MVC. Solo intento crear un login pero no se como hacer para que aparezca cuando se creó el elemento en automatico o manual

Comment: Por favor, si te funciono la repuesta recuerda "ACEPTAR" para que otros Usuarios se beneficien de ella.

Answer (score 0):

Lo puedes hacer mediante JavaScript via fetch, aqui esta el codigo: (Avisame si tienes dudas):

```
client_type = document.getElementById("client_type");
client_type.onchange = () => {
let valor = client_type.value;
let ruta = `archivo.php?seleccionar=${valor}`;

// Enviamos nuestra petición al servidor 
// con fecth:
fetch(ruta)
    .then(respuesta => respuesta.text())
    .then(data => {
        console.log(data);
    })};
```

En la primera linea identificamos el select para luego tomar el valor, con el evento onchange esperamos que este valor sea seleccionado y aplicamos el fech, para esto te recomiendo colocar un primer option que sea seleccione... `<option value="" selected>Seleccione...</option>` para que esto cambie y tome el valor, es importante validar que el campo no esta en blanco cuando haga el cambio y mediante el fecth lo enviamos por GET, tambien lo puedes hacer mediante POST (seria mas seguro).